# Data Loader v58.x

Tags: data-loader

Using Upsert to load data with the bulk options enabled, I discover that data for mapped fields are not uploading into the Salesforce environment. I've discovered this in the 58.x versions. This wasn't happening in previous versions. The records that have missing data are in the Success log and I can see the missing data in the fields. If I disable the bulk options, all the data loads.

Has anyone else has/had this issue? Any suggestions?

Thanks!

(my first question posted)

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) and [take the tour](/tour). Including a [Minimal, Complete and Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be helpful.